# Why is array empty after reading lines of file and push it in

Tags: arrays, node.js

I'm wondering why my array is empty after reading the lines of a file in this little `node` script:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');
var arr = [];

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('file.txt')
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
  arr.push(line);
});

console.log(arr); // []
```

is there anything I am missing here how the binding works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readline is asynchronous, so 'line' is called multiple times, while your current `console.log(arr);` is called before all `rl.on('line', (line) =>` calls have finished.

You'll need to use the 'close' event

> The rl.close() method is called and the readline.Interface instance has relinquished control over the input and output streams;

So change your code to this:

```
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');
var arr = [];

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('file.txt')
});

rl.on('close', (line) => {
  console.log(arr);
  //and anything else you want to do once finished processing
});

// this will fire before 'close'
console.log('This fired before rl had finished');
```

Comment: No, there shouldn't be any need to.

Comment: You'll just need to be 'async' all the way - return a callback inside `rl.on('close` if you need to